Sync MongoDB Realm data without user accounts
Question
Is there a way to sync a Realm database to the cloud without making users create an account / sign up? The data should be accessible across the user's devices (ex: if they install the app on a new device, their data must be synced).
The main reason I don't want users to create accounts as it'll probably reduce the number of users which actually pay for the app (no one likes having to make an account).
Potential approaches

Using a Mongo sync-enabled realm instance. This would automatically back up all realm data to a mongo cloud database. Although this requires a user account to tie data to a specific user. There is the option for anonymous users, although this is generally used for free trials rather than full paid features as users can't recover their account if on a new device.
Cloud Kit sync. This would be the best solution for iOS as users are generally already signed into iCloud which means they wouldn't have to create an account with my app. There seems to be really big complexities with this approach though as there's no easy way to move a realm database to cloud kit especially when using React Native.

Context
I have a fully free React Native app listed on the iOS App Store which uses Realm for data storage. Since I'm using Realm locally, there are no user accounts - a user simply needs to open the app and their data is automatically saved to a local Realm database. If a user deletes the app or installs it on another device, they lose all their data.
To make sure users don't lose their data, I'd like to add a cloud sync feature which syncs their local data to a cloud service (like Mongo, iCloud, etc). The feature will only be available to paid users, as it'd be one of many premium app features.
Any advice would be really appreciated! Thanks.

This question is really asking for opinions/advice and that's off topic for SO - it may get your question closed. It's not a bad question, just not a good question for this site as without really knowing the entire use case, any answers would just be a guess. So as a comment; Realm is just a file on the users device and if the goal is to move that file from one device to another when it's the paid version, CloudKit can do that pretty easily. If on the other hand, you want Sync'ing, it could be done with CloudKit but Realm/Atlas (events, live data etc) is absolutely the way to go.
